# Qué hago para que aplique los cambios uno por uno y no todos a la vez

Tags: javascript

Le quiero cambiar los colores a los botones automaticamente con el **setTimeout** o  **el setInterval** al dar click, pero sucede que se los cambia todos a la vez y no uno por uno, sincronizado...

¿Qué tengo que modificar para conseguir el resultado que quiero? **usando el ciclo for clásico nada de for each, ya se que son lo mismo pero hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo y familiarizándome con for**

```js
function color() {
var umder = document.querySelectorAll(".button > button");


setInterval(function(){

for (var i = 0; i < umder.length; i++) {

umder[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";

}

}, 2000);

}
color();
```

```html
<div class="button">
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Es decir que sin dar clic se cambien uno tras otro después de 2 segundos el color a cada botón?

Comment: @Aprendiz al dar click a la function color() se ejecuta

Comment: Si el efecto para el color de fondo se va ejecutar cuando el usuario de clic en cada botón, entonces para que quieres el `setInterval` ?

Comment: No, al dar click quiero que comience a cambiar el color automáticamente uno por uno, pero no he logrado esa parte, el de elegir uno por uno y se vaya aplicando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function color() {
var umder = document.querySelectorAll(".button > button");
 var t = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < umder.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(x) {
      return function() {
        umder[x].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    } (i), 2000 * t);
  t++;
  }

}
color();
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>
```

podrías realizarle con un setTimeout ya que el set interval se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo y va a cambiando a todos prueba con esto

```
function color() {
var umder = document.querySelectorAll(".button > button");
    var t = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < umder.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(x) {
      return function() {
        umder[x].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    } (i), 2000 * t);
        t++;
  }

}
color();
```